# не обновляются записи в таблице

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Имеется таблица с полями `ID`, `Fam`, `Name`, `Otch`, `Number`, `Otdel`. Пытаюсь внести изменения записи через форму и ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, вероятные ошибки в данном случае.

```
<?php

/* Соединяемся с базой данных */
$hostname = "localhost"; // название/путь сервера, с MySQL
$username = "root"; // имя пользователя 
$password = "123"; // пароль пользователя 
$dbName = "rfid"; // название базы данных

/* Таблица MySQL, в которой хранятся данные */
$table = "sotrudniki";

/* Создаем соединение */
$connection=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die ("Не могу создать соединение");

/* Выбираем базу данных. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее */
mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbName) or die (mysqli_error());

/* Если была нажата кнопка редактирования, вносим изменения */
if(@$submit_edit) {

$query = "UPDATE $table SET Fam='$Fam' WHERE (ID='$update')";
/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die (mysqli_error());
}

/* Заносим в переменную $res всю базу данных */
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
/* Выполняем запрос. Если произойдет ошибка - вывести ее. */
$res = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
/* Узнаем количество записей в базе данных */
$row = mysqli_num_rows($res);

/* Выводим данные из таблицы */
echo ("
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >

<head>

    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1251\" />

    <title>Редактирование и обновление данных</title>

<style type=\"text/css\">
<!--
body { font: 12px Georgia; color: #666;background-image: url(../images/bg.png); }
h3 { font-size: 16px; text-align: center; }
table { width: 400px; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 5px auto; background: #E6E6E6; }
td { padding: 3px; vertical-align: middle; }
input { width: 250px; border: solid 1px #CCC; color: #FF6666; }
textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px; border: solid 1px #CCC; color: #FF6666; }
.buttons { width: auto; border: double 1px #666; background: #D6D6D6; color: #000; }
#num { width: 20px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5px; float: right; }
-->
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h3>Редактирование и обновление данных в таблице MySQL</h3>
");

/* Цикл вывода данных из базы конкретных полей */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<form action=\"update_data.php\" method=\"post\" name=\"edit_form\">\n";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"update\" value=\"".$row["ID"]."\" />\n";
    echo "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\" style=\"border-bottom:solid 1px #CCCCCC;\"><b><i><div id=\"num\">#".$row["ID"]."</div>";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Фамилия пользователя:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['Fam']."\" name=\"Fam\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Имя пользователя:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['Name']."\" name=\"Name\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Отчество пользователя:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['Otch']."\" name=\"Otch\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td>Номер карты:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['Number']."\" name=\"Number\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
     echo "<td>Отдел:</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['Otdel']."\" name=\"Otdel\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
    echo "<td colspan=\"2\" align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_edit\" class=\"buttons\" value=\"Сохранить изменения\" /></td>\n";
    echo "</tr></table></form>\n\n";
}

/* Закрываем соединение */
mysqli_close($connection);

/* Выводим ссылку возврата */
echo ("<div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;\"><a href=\"workers.php\">Вернуться назад</a></div>");

?>
```

Comment: При поиске возможной ошибки, убрал все поля, которые нужно обновлять, кроме поля Fam, забыл вернуть обратно перед тем, как вставлять код.

Comment: Кто такие `$update` и `$Fam`? Они не определены судя по тексту.... +  зачем вам `@` у  `$submit_edit` ? Вы хотите вывод ошибок но при этом их гасите, это вроде неразумно..........`ничего не происходит` значит ваш `mysqli_error())` должен показать проблему ......... зачем вы так через задний проход выводите форму эхом? Почитайте об альтернативном синтаксисе циклов и операторов `if`

Comment: А не апдейтит ничего потому, что в условие `if(@$submit_edit) {` даже не входит

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите суперглобальный массив **$_POST**
И кто вообще вас учил так писать?
Жесть какая - то...
У конструкции **echo** есть прототип передачи переменных and so on (и так далее).

Вообщем, при отправки формы просто сделайте:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

И все поймете.